# Why the `typedef` can distinguish the define syntax?

Tags: c, typedef

The case of `typedef` usage:

```
struct tagPOINT
{  
    int x;  
    int y;  
};  

typedef struct tagPOINT MyPoint;

MyPoint point = {1, 2};
```

You see this line code: `typedef struct tagPOINT MyPoint;`

why the `typedef` can distinguish the code then divide to `struct tagPOINT` and `MyPoint`, instead of `struct` and `tagPOINT MyPoint`?

Comment: do you understand `struct tagPoint x;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `typedef` keyword serves as a storage class specifier in the syntax:

```
typedef struct tagPOINT MyPoint;
```

In other words, syntactically it occupies the same place in the phrase structure as `extern` or `static`:

```
extern struct tagPOINT MyPoint;
```

Here we have the basic phrase structure, going by my memory rather than an ISO document:

```
<storage-class-specifier> <specifier-qualifier-list> <declarator> ;
```

`typedef` is the storage class specifier list, `struct tagPOINT` is the type specifier comprising the specifier-qualifier list, and `MyPoint` is the declarator.

Your C compiler's parser sorts all of this out according to the grammar.

In other words, it's not simply the case that `typedef` is some kind of command in a command language, having to analyze it arguments in some *ad hoc* way.

Answer (score 3):

In the C grammar, the only token that can come after a `struct` keyword is either an *identifier* or a `{`. If it is an identifier, it is a structure tag (which is a name for the structure). So, whenever the compiler sees `struct tagPOINT`, it knows `tagPOINT` is a structure tag, even if it has some other meaning when it is not immediately after `struct`.